# Wrong syntax for OVER and PARTITION in MySQL syntax

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, window-functions, mysql-5.7

```
SELECT Id, Price, CustomerId, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerId)
FROM Orders;
```

I get the error "Syntax error: Unexpected '(' (opening parenthesis)

Does MySQL not support this? I'm pretty sure I've done this before and from what I see on google this should work.

```
mysql -V
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.32, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

Comment: do `select version();` to get the server version; what you show is just the command line client version which isn't necessarily at all related

Comment: The `Ver 14.14` is misleading. That is the version of the `mysql` client app, but the MySQL Server is what determines the SQL syntax it supports. The client and the server each have their own version number and they are not in sync. This is genuinely confusing, I know. :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Window functions are available in MySQL 8.0 only.

In earlier versions, you can use a subquery - however, your code is missing an `ORDER BY` clause, which makes the sort inconsistant. Assuming that you want to sort orders of the same customer by their id, you would phrase this as:

```
SELECT Id, Price, CustomerId, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Orders o1 WHERE o1.CustomerId = o.CustomerId and o1.Id <= o.Id) AS rn
FROM Orders o;
```

Comment: I'm not experienced with MySQL, I saw the Ver 14.14 and I thought I had a version higher than 8.0. Apparently it's the other number! Thanks

Comment: @Lucas: indeed: you are running 5.7.32. `select version()` gives you that information unambiguously.